# AWS SNS publishing always disables endpoint (invalid token)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to use a Lambda function to send a notification to an iOS device using SNS, but every time I send it, the status of the endpoint changes to false and an error appears in CloudWatch saying invalid token (below).

I have confirmed that the token is the same one as phone's, and that it is sending to that.  I have also tried to regenerate the certificates 3 times now, and the same error still appears.

CloudWatch error

```
{
    "status": "FAILURE",
    "notification": {
        "timestamp": "2015-10-20 03:27:46.5",
        "messageId": "id",
        "messageMD5Sum": "sum"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "statusCode": 8,
        "dwellTimeMs": 473,
        "token": "f0b1abebdbc08d4f0c46a7a0620e518af886952c9f8e21e22cff5a5fc5ca5098",
        "attempts": 1,
        "providerResponse": "NotificationErrorResponse(command=8, status=InvalidToken, id=1, cause=null)",
        "destination": "destination endpoint arn"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that I was using a production certificate and it was all in development (building from Xcode).  Switching everything to a development app in SNS fixed it.

Comment: For anyone else having trouble, be sure to check your project settings in Xcode to make sure the device you are trying to use is set up correctly when trying to use the sandbox... Somehow my app was running on my iPad, even though Xcode reported it was not provisioned under project settings / General / Identity. The automatic Fix Issue button located there fixed it, and sure enough the next time the app ran, I got a new APNS token which then worked just fine.